# How to write an quote in php

Tags: php, quote, backspace

produce code to output the string

> "It's not more than £3"

including all speech marks.

How can I do that? I am stuck. 
That's what I wrote :

```
echo "\" It's not more than "\\£3''";
```

but it's not working!

Comment: Refer to [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: "It is working" - "it's working" - "it\"s working" - "it"s not working" - 'it's not working'

Comment: You successfully managed to escape the first quote, but horribly failed the last one? Why?

Comment: What's going on with `"\\`?  That's not in the original string

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "\"It's not more than £3\"";
```